# Docusign embedded signing request from template

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create an embedded signing request from a template that I've created in my docusign account. I'm using Node JS and I can't seem to find the documentation on how to do this. The closest thing I've found are these quick start examples: https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#quickstart but the embedded signing section confuses me even further because I don't see the "custom signing url" anywhere in the code, even though it was references in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope%20from%20a%20Template.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____39) should get you started sending envelopes from your template. The recipient parameter is where you'll add the clientUserId to make the recipient embedded. Once the envelope is sent then you'll call the [POST recipient view](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Post%20Recipient%20View.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____93) to get the URL for signing.

Comment: I'm having, the same issue, but these links are not valid any more.

Comment: I am also having the same issue, can't seem to figure this out.