# Docusign embedded signing request from template with nodejs

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the nodejs docusign api and am having trouble figuring out how do embedded signing request from template. I kinda want it working the way the example does for non template usage.

The main issue i am having is with the way the nodejs docusign library handles recipientIds when you are using a template, cant set the recipientIds directly when you use the template and doesnt seem to take the recipients set automatically by docusign

Most of my code wasfollowing the [quickstart guide](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-signing)

Yes I have read, but found the answers unhelpful.

[Docusign embedded signing request from template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377484/docusign-embedded-signing-request-from-template) and [Docusign Embedded Signing using template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248976/docusign-embedded-signing-using-template)

Comment: Would you edit your question with your code? Also are you seeing any errors?

Comment: Something about recipientIds not being valid, it is kinda looking like an error in the library itself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    function makeEnvelope(args){
        // create the envelope definition
        let env = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
        env.templateId = args.templateId;
    
        // Create template role elements to connect the signer and cc recipients
        // to the template
        // We're setting the parameters via the object creation
        let signer1 = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
            email: args.signerEmail,
            name: args.signerName,
            clientUserId: '1',
            roleName: 'signer'});
    
    
        // Add the TemplateRole objects to the envelope object
        env.templateRoles = [signer1];
        env.status = "sent"; // We want the envelope to be sent
    
        return env;
    }
    
    {
       let dsApiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
        dsApiClient.setBasePath(args.basePath);
        dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + args.accessToken);
        let envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApiClient);
        
        // Step 1. Make the envelope request body (function above)
        let envelope = makeEnvelope(args.envelopeArgs)
    
        // Step 2. call Envelopes::create API method
        // Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
        let results = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(
            args.accountId, {envelopeDefinition: envelope});
    
        return results;
    }

function makeRecipientViewRequest(args) {

    let viewRequest = new docusign.RecipientViewRequest();

    viewRequest.returnUrl = args.dsReturnUrl + "?state=123";

    viewRequest.authenticationMethod = 'none';
    
    viewRequest.email = args.signerEmail;
    viewRequest.userName = args.signerName;
    viewRequest.clientUserId = args.signerClientId;

    viewRequest.pingFrequency = 600; // seconds
    viewRequest.pingUrl = args.dsPingUrl; // optional setting

    return viewRequest
}
```

Comment: I can already do something similar, how do i use embedded signing with an envelope created with the nodejs docusign library

Comment: Inbar is using the node SDK ^

Comment: I am referred to embedded signing, not just making an envelope ^^

Comment: ok, let me add the code for this as well. One second

Comment: added the last function for this purpose at the bottom

Comment: where is the recipientId, is the ping frequency even needed, did you even test this, in my authenticationMethod, I use 'None', but might not matter.

I'll just have to look at my code again.

I was doing something extremely similar.

Comment: recipientId is not required, ping is optional. I tested this. None is ok for authentication method for embedded.
Make sure you have clientUserId. That may have been your issue.

Comment: I was trying to find a similar example but this code makes no sense. There is no context and the JS syntax is broken. Is there a better working example of basic template signing?

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/lib/eSignature/examples/useTemplate.js

Comment: This code works in conjuncture with the quickstart - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/